# How to calculate the 2019 WHO Cardiovascular Risk using R?

Tags: r, stat

How can I calculate the 2019 WHO Cardiovascular Risk using R programming language? Is there a package? There is a R code to calculate the 2007 WHO Cardiovascular Risk chart and I can't find an updated version of it. whoishRisk – an R package - https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5345772/

Comment: Try `devtools::install_github("DylanRJCollins/whoishRisk")`. The date is 2017, not 2019 but updated from a 2007 version.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. However DylanRJCollins/whoishRisk R package is to calculate the old version of Cardiovascular Risk which is 2007, isn't it?